# Jquery declare variables at once

Tags: php, jquery, global-variables

How to declaring jquery variables to use in each function/event? my script is look 'ugly' to declare var repeatly in each event, how to change 'once for all' var and use within document?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var keyword = $("#autocomplete").val();
        group = <?php echo $tb->group ?>;
        uid = <?php echo $tb->uid ?>;

    loadData(1, group, uid, '');

    $('#btn_search').click(function(){
        var keyword = $("#autocomplete").val();
            group = <?php echo $tb->group ?>;
            uid = <?php echo $tb->uid ?>;
        loadData(1,group,uid,keyword);
    });

    $('body').on('click touchend', '#list-container .pagination li.go', function(){
        var page = $(this).attr('p');
            group = <?php echo $tb->group ?>;
            uid = <?php echo $tb->uid ?>;
            keyword = $("#autocomplete").val();

        loadData(page,group,uid,keyword);
    });

});

function loadData(page,group,uid,keyword){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: { 
            page:page,
            group:group,
            uid:uid,
            keyword:keyword 
        },
        success: function(response){
            $('#output').html(response.html);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You have only defined `keyword` and `page` variables. All others are implicitly global because you separated them with semicolons instead of commas.

Answer (score 0):

declare variable without var keyword
then it will be a global variable around inside of window object

```
    keyword = $("#autocomplete").val();
    group = <?php echo $tb->group ?>;
    uid = <?php echo $tb->uid ?>;
```

oer use like this

```
    window.keyword = $("#autocomplete").val();
    window.group = <?php echo $tb->group ?>;
    window.uid = <?php echo $tb->uid ?>;
```

modified your code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        keyword = $("#autocomplete").val();
        group = <?php echo $tb->group ?>;
        uid = <?php echo $tb->uid ?>;

    loadData(1, group, uid, '');

    $('#btn_search').click(function(){
        loadData(1,group,uid,keyword);
    });

    $('body').on('click touchend', '#list-container .pagination li.go', function(){
        var page = $(this).attr('p');
        loadData(page,group,uid,keyword);
    });

});

function loadData(page,group,uid,keyword){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: { 
            page:page,
            group:group,
            uid:uid,
            keyword:keyword 
        },
        success: function(response){
            $('#output').html(response.html);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `$('#btn_search').click(function(){...}` doesn't work after remove var within the event, any solution?